# Trying to upload videos using PHP but keep getting "No File Selected" on certain videos

Tags: php, file, upload, isset

Heres a basic demo of what Im trying to figure out. I can upload certain vid files but some say No File Selected for some reason and I cannot find out why. They are all mp4 videos and about the same size.

HTML:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

PHP file:

```
if(!isset($_FILES['file']) || $_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
    echo "Error no file selected"; 
} else {
    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

I upload demo.mp4 which is 5MB it works. I upload test.mp4 which is 6MB I get "Error no file selected".

Anyone know why this is? Ive tried 4 similar mp4 files and only one gets set. I wouldn't think it has anything to do with server settings or ini file settings as the file isn't even set to read the file data like size.

Comment: It most likely does have to do with server settings or ini file settings. Check what the error message is when you get "Error no file selected" and give https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php a read.

Comment: Yeah I went through the ini file and everything seems ok, I cant get it to throw any error other than no file. If it doesnt see a file selected it wont proceed to any errors which is frustrating to error check..

Comment: This is really odd, the only way I can get that error to trigger is if I select the file in the form, then rename it on my computer before pressing upload.

Comment: Honestly one f the most frustrating errors i've dealt with since I cant actually get a error lol

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured it out, I had changed the post_max_size in the ini but it didn't save for some reason. I increased it now and the problem is solved.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense actually, since it was larger than post_max_size, the entire thing was thrown away before the script was loaded, leading to the no file uploaded error.

Comment: Yep exactly. Live and learn :-)